# ionic 3 rest api authentication

Tags: angular, ionic3, restful-authentication, typescript-typings

I am trying to build a login page on ionic 3
Below is the code i am using 
On home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

import { ServicesProvider } from '../../providers/services/services';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

    userData = { username:'', password:'' };
  data : any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public servicesProvider: ServicesProvider) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad HomePage');
    }


  logIn() {
    this.servicesProvider.login(this.userData).then((result)=>{
      this.data = result;
    });
  }

}
```

On services.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {RequestOptions, Request, RequestMethod} from '@angular/http';


import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';


let apiUrl = 'http://9.xxx.xxx.xxx/test/xxxxx.aspx';


@Injectable()
export class ServicesProvider {

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello ServicesProvider Provider');
  }

  login(credentials) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

        this.http.post(apiUrl, JSON.stringify(credentials), {headers: headers})
          .subscribe(res => {
            resolve(res.json());
          }, (err) => {
            reject(err);
          });
    });
  }

}
```

The response i get :
 `{"message":"failure","status":"Blank_Username","response":"Provide Username"}`

while checking the log on browser

The response i get on google POST MAN : `{"message":"success","status":"Auth_Successful","response":"Authentication successful"}`

I pass the username and password on the request body on POST MAN, it responds fine.

What I need to understand is am I sending the username and password parameters the wrong way using angular 4?
What could be the other options to send the username and password as parameters using ionic 3 (angular 4).

Comment: Best way is why dont you create login model and send to service?

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong (i am new to angular and mobile app development as a whole)
home page is my login model and i am sending the request to services on the services.ts page
Is it different that what you are suggesting ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show your backend code where it handles the post request

Answer (score 0):

Can you try defining the header like this

```
this.http.post(apiUrl, JSON.stringify(credentials), {
   headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
})
```

maybe the request does not have the correct content type

another thing you could try is looking at the postman call you are doing,It might be sending the data as url encoded, and you call should change to something like this

```
 let url = `grant_type=password&username=${credentials.username}&password=${credentials.password}`;
 return this
        ._http
        .post(apiUrl, url, {
             headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

use HttpHeaders

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders({
   'Accept': 'application/json',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your `userData.username`
It is set to an empty string by default

```
userData = { username:'', password:'' };
```

Update the value of the `{userData}` fields (maybe through a form) and you should get the right response.